# location service in the background execution

Tags: iphone, ios

I want to get the location of my device 24x7 times. but as per apple documentation, apps can only be run for the max 10 minutes.After that, apps is automatically killed.
I am using the below code:

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
UIApplication * app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
bgTask = [app beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler: ^ {
    dispatch_async (dispatch_get_main_queue (), ^ {
        if (bgTask != UIBackgroundTaskInvalid)
        {
            [app endBackgroundTask: bgTask];
            bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
        }
    });
}];

// Start the long-running task and return immediately.

dispatch_async (dispatch_get_global_queue (DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^ {
    lm.locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
    lm.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation;
    [lm.locationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
    [lm.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

    dispatch_async (dispatch_get_main_queue (), ^ {
        if (bgTask != UIBackgroundTaskInvalid) {
            [app endBackgroundTask: bgTask];
            bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
        }
    });
});
}
```

I have also included **supported Background Mode** as **Requires location**.

But the app runs for only 10 minutes. How can i make the app to run all the time. Please help me out!

Comment: what have you written in `didUpdateLocations:`?

Comment: Right now, i am just getting the location in the log. log stops after 10-15mins since the app is in background.

Comment: `significantLocationChanges` does not require you to implement the background task. just remove the bgtask creation and run it normally with the Supported Background Mode key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`significantLocationChanges` does not require you to implement the background task. just remove the bgtask creation and run it normally with the Supported Background Mode key.

Scheduled BackgroundTasks are killed by OS approx after 10 mins and hence your location service monitoring. So u only need to remove the BGTask that u are creating for location updates.